# CreateView not uploading image and name of the user for a post

Tags: django

I'm making a web app which allows users to register to the site and let them post their posts.
For taking in their post I have used the built in CBV: CreateView. In the user post I take in the name of the user using foreignkey with null=True, image, title.

The problem is: when I go to the detail page of that post it shows that there is no file associated with the image field, so I made an if statement to check if the post contains an image. But then too, it does not show the image. It shows User:None.

I don't know what is happening, I have read that CBV take the self.request automatically and there is no need to link the current user to the post.

Following are the screenshots of my code:

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vowZ.png)

[browser image before clicking submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kidn9.png)

[browser image after clicking submit button (detail page of the post)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UyA1.png)

[post_detail.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3iHh.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpNhX.png)

Comment: show UserPostForm

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in you database than you can render it this way

```
<a href=""> <img src="{{post_detail.image.url}}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I forgot to add the  enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form of my createview html.
Now it's working perfectly fine.

[Screenshot of userpost_form.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrPP2.png)

Thank you all for all the support.